# What are some use cases for adding arguments in a graphql non-query object type?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

As the graphql documentation shows, it's possible to add arguments to a regular object type in your schema.

```
type Starship {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  length(unit: LengthUnit = METER): Float
}
```

I understand how this is useful for the query type, but not for regular object types. What are some reasons you might want to add arguments to object types?

Answer (score 0):

The first example that comes in my mind is if you have a field such as `photo` and you may ask for various sizes:

```
{
  me {
    id
    name
    small: photo( scale: 0.5 )
    normal: photo
    large: photo( scale: 2 )
  }
}
```

Dates with various formats, anything from transformations to filters and whatnot. It's up to you. I'm really crappy with examples, but you get the point.

Comment: if the input is for asking for various sizes, wouldn't those inputs but part of the query object?

`type Query {
  hero(episode: Episode): Character
  droid(id: ID!): Droid
}`

Comment: Every field on a GraphQL object type can have arguments. Not just the fields on the Query or Mutation types

Comment: yes. but under what situations would adding arguments to non-query or non-mutation types be helpful? would it be used if i needed to write a special resolver for some nested object?

Comment: You can write a resolver for every field on whatever type you want. Only you know If you need any arguments for resolving that field.Take a `User` type with a `friends` field. You might want to pass some arguments to the `friends` resolver for pagination, filtering or sorting... whatever.